# link_to different behavior from rails2 to rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In rails2, I was able to have code like this:

```
link_to(user.company.name, user.company)
```

which would map to:

```
/companies/id
```

but in rails 3, this same line of code throws a error stating:

```
undefined method `user_companies_path'
```

The obvious fix is to do something like:

```
link_to(user.company.name, company_path(user.company))
```

But I was wondering if anyone could explain the reason behind the change? The logic seemed a lot cleaner.

**EDIT: Adding samples of my routes**

In rails2, my routes looked like:

```
map.resources :users, :except => :edit, :member => { :details => :get }
map.resources :companies, :except => :edit, :member => { :details => :get }
```

In rails3, my routes are:

```
resources :users, :except => :edit do
  member do
    get :details
  end
end

resources :companies, :except => :edit do
  member do
    get :details
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the Rails 3 routing API bases your application on resources which is why these RESTful routes are being used, and also means that it does things like support constraints.

In Rails 2, you'd do:

```
resources :cars do
  resource :models

  member do
    post :year
  end

  collection do
    get :details
  end
end
```

In Rails 3, you'd do:

```
map.resources :cars, :member => {:year => :post}, :collection => {:details => :get} do |cars|
  cars.resource :model
end
```

You also have the `:as` key available which means you can then use named route helpers anywhere that `url_for` is available (i.e. controllers, mailers etc.)

Comment: In my rails 2 app, I was also using resources (none of which were nested). I've updated the original question with snippets of my routes